# Ipad type navigation buttons

Tags: css

Ipad type navigation buttons

I wanted to have ipad type navigation buttons. I was able to get tutorial on this http://css3wizardry.com/2010/06/28/create-back-next-buttons-with-css3/
But this doesn't work on firefox. I have attached pic of image below. Any help in getting done in css would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the tutorial (for some reason) uses webkit-only CSS3 properties. Wherever there's a property that starts with `-webkit-`, make identical copies with prefixes for other browsers:

```
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-o-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;
```

If you target only newer browsers that support CSS3 directly you can just use the last property (no prefix at all).